# TypeError for optional start parameter in string.find()

Tags: python, string, python-2.x

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how this is happening. When I run the following:

```
def find_in_string(string, ch):
    count = 0
    index = 0
    while 0 <= index < len(string):
        if string.find(string, ch, index) != -1:
            return True

find_in_string('asdfasdf', 's')
```

Here's what is I get:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

However, running this through the interpreter like so:

```
index = 0
if string.find('asdfasdf', 's', index) != -1:
    return True
```

It returns 'True'. So I'm not understanding how string.find isn't getting passed an integer for the starting index in the above function. Any advice appreciated!

**EDIT:**
For whatever reason, the above function now works after importing string again. Perhaps too much coffee?

Comment: Here's some advice:  Don't use `string` as a variable name.  It's a commonly used module that comes with python.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I thought that might have something to do with it so i fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your misunderstanding seems to come from importing the `string` module as well as naming your variable `string`.

You don't need to import the module to use `find`, and you could name your variable something else if you do need to import the module to do something else.

The type is `str` not `string`.

[`find`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) doesn't work like that. You mean

```
string.find(ch) # ', index' if you want
```

if your variable is named `string` or

```
str.find(string, ch) # ', index' if you want
```

if your variable is named `string` and you really want to access it on the class / type `str` (no reason to).

You call `find` on the string you're searching in, you don't pass the string to `find` manually unless you're accessing `find` on the class / type. `find`s first manually passed argument is the string to search for, followed by `start` and `end` indexes. Since you appear to be searching the whole string, they can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks a heap! I'm not really sure why I thought calling find in this way was a good idea. :)